# Recycler view load more data from the JSON

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to load more data from the `JSON`, I'm trying assign it to value but its rewriting to the Zero, when I pass to the `JSON url` using the recycler view to it

```
    int scrollX = rootScrollView.getScrollX(); 
using the 

    recyclerview.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollChanged() {
 Log.i("TEst","scroll:"+scrollX);(I want to increment this Value so that i can send that integer into json to load more data)
}
```

Comment: You want to load data before user sees it?

Comment: yes like flipkart and snapdeal

Comment: so you should basically load data at certain point/value like say if you have 20 items in your `RecyclerView` so you should start loading more data at 15th or 17th position in your `RecyclerView`.

Comment: yes but how can i set that?